# Should JavaScript only be loaded when it's needed?

Tags: javascript

I'm using jQuery for a project and have probably a dozen or so additional jQuery plugins/addons (tipsy, uniform, jeditable, fancybox, etc, etc).

As a best-practice, should I only be loading those when a page needs them?

Or am I better off just loading them all right from the start so they are in the browser's cache and just be done with it instead of having to programmatically include the code when it's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You have to make the judgement based on load sizes and times with and without the files. If the whole thing is a reasonable size with the files, you may as well just include them all. Otherwise, include them when needed. Or you might even want to include them at different times along a user's journey through the site, so that when they reach a page which needs lots of them, they don't all have to load at once. Unless you're talking about massive file sizes (which I doubt) it probably won't make a huge difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should only load the scripts that are required on the page.

Every file you add is an additional call to your server (assuming no minifying), adding to the load and to the traffic.

On the client side, it is again, extra traffic and the browser needs to parse it.

It may be easier to put all of them in every page, however, will all people go to all pages and need all scripts?

It's a trade off and you need to test both your server and clients to see what works best in your situation.

Comment: Regarding additional calls, I can just cache all the code into one single .js file if needed...which eliminates the extra calls completely.

Comment: @Shipgford - True, minifying helps, but you still have the traffic overhead and the browser still needs to parse it all.

Comment: I'll second Oded here - you should only ever be loading what you need, and nothing more. Even if you combine it into one file that the user can cache, what's the point of sending down more data than you need?

Comment: 5 requests to the server vs. 1 cached for the site?? Every page will likely include another script to load. I can see it both ways, but more often than not the single file cache is best. I've done ridiculous amounts of speed testing, and filesize isn't the biggest detractor, it's server requests. The number of requests is the fulcrum of load-time. I also think it's quite brash to say "best practice" :\

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on the groupings you're referncing, but yes if its something like 5 scripts, just string them together with a [minify](http://see.weareinto.com/3tg6) request and be done with it. Then it's cached and doesn't have to check the servers any more.

You can see what I've done [here](http://see.weareinto.com/3tg6) with this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tylerbel.com/workspace/min/f=workspace/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js,workspace/js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js,workspace/js/main.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could look at module loading, the new hawtness: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

For me I have found that if you are using PHP, you can easily define what you want called. What I do is I have a a predefined header that called on one js file which I have made php. On the php js file, I have each script under a session than unset the session within the if statement. Than on the page I am using that calls the header I place at the top suppose $_SESSION['chatjs'] = '1';...On the php js I would use if(isset($_SESSION['chatjs'])){ include('whatever.js); unset($_SESSION['chatjs']); } which has helped speed up my site from  second load time to 0.035 load time per page give or take depending on what all is on the page.